# Postman minute not updating after each request

Tags: postman, momentjs, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

In my pre-request script section I am simply doing:

```
const moment = require('moment');
console.log(moment().add(1,'minutes').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM"));
console.log(moment().add(2,'months').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM"));
```

Which outputs:

```
2020-07-29 22:07
2020-09-29 22:07
```

However, subsequent calls to that endpoint do not update the time it always stays at 22:07 even though the time is now 22:28.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct format `mm` not `MM` as per the official [DOCS](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) to achieve the desired results.

Run snippet below.

```js
let addMin = moment().add(1,'minutes').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
console.log(addMin);

let addMonth = moment().add(2,'months').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
console.log(addMonth);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ElliotReeve Glad that i could help. Happy coding.